# Problems with publishing Dashboards in Tableau Public

Tags: save, visualization, tableau-api, bi-tool

While going through Google Data Analytics Certification I have come across the Tableau. Particularly, I am using Tableau Public (Free Web Version).

The problem is, I could not save dashboards I have created do to the
**'Couldn’t save workbook Tableau experienced an unexpected server error. Try again, or contact your Tableau Server Administrator.** error.

Googling did not help much since no-one seems to know how to resolve this issue.